# How to list all files in the directories

Tags: perl

how can i list all files in parent and sub directories for multilpe dirs?

```
 $dir="/home/httpd/cgi-bin/r/met";

    opendir(DIR,"/home/httpd/cgi-bin/r/met")||die"error";

    while($line=readdir DIR)
    {

    print"$line\n";

    opendir DIR1,"$dir/$line"||die"error";

        while($line1=readdir DIR1)
        {
         print"$line1\n";
         }
    }
    closedir DIR;
    closedir DIR1;
```

Comment: So if I get it right you have a list of directory's where you want to get all files from? OR do you want to get all files with sub directory's ?

Comment: Think what you are serching for is recursive call of your method. Which language perl or php why tags string regex and string-comparison?

Comment: i need answer in perl language

Answer (score 4):

Don't do it this way, use `File::Find` instead.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

 my $search = "/home/httpd/cgi-bin/r/met";

 sub print_file_names {
    print $_,"\n";
 }

 find ( \&print_file_names, $search );
```

Comment: whether it will support to all files in parent and sub directory for multiple folders

Comment: Yes, it will do a full traversal of the directory structure.

Comment: `$_` will give you the current filename (basename). If you need the full path, use `$File::Find::name`. If you want the current directory for some reason, use `$File::Find::dir`.

Answer (score 0):

[File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) effectively walks through list of directories and executes a subroutine defined by you for each file or directory found recursively below the starting directory. Before calling your subroutine `find` (a function exported by `File::Find` module) by default changes to the directory being scanned and sets the following (global) variables:

- `$File::Find::dir` -- visited directory path relative to the starting directory
- `$File::Find::name` -- full path of the file being visited relative to the starting directory
- `$_` -- basename of the file being visited (used in my example)

One way to solve your problem would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Usage: ffind [dir1 ...] 
use strict; use warnings;
use 5.010;    # to be able to use say
use File::Find;

# use current working directory if no command line argument
@ARGV = qw(.) unless @ARGV;

find( sub { say if -f }, @ARGV );
```